# Docker 1.12 Port Fowarding Services Across Nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

So I've got a Plex server running on my Docker swarm!! If I kill a node magically it'll start Plex somewhere else. This is great! Now comes the fun part...

With old-school containers I would just port forward port 32400 on my router to the server that was running Plex and it would work find. Now that Plex can run in multiple different places I need to figure out how to forward the port to some static resource. I could use HAProxy to bind some bridge interface and run it on every node to provide failover...but I'd like to see if there's an easier way to accomplish this.

**What's the best way to forward ports to services in Docker Swarm?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port forwarding is built into the new swarm mode. There's a [section on load balancing](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/#/load-balancing) in the documentation:

> The swarm manager uses ingress load balancing to expose the services
>   you want to make available externally to the swarm. The swarm manager
>   can automatically assign the service a PublishedPort or you can
>   configure a PublishedPort for the service in the 30000-32767 range.
>
> External components, such as cloud load balancers, can access the
>   service on the PublishedPort of any node in the cluster whether or not
>   the node is currently running the task for the service. All nodes in
>   the swarm cluster route ingress connections to a running task
>   instance.
>
> Swarm mode has an internal DNS component that automatically assigns
>   each service in the swarm a DNS entry. The swarm manager uses internal
>   load balancing to distribute requests among services within the
>   cluster based upon the DNS name of the service.

---

### Update

The following article discusses how to integrate a proxy load balancer into the docker engine

- https://technologyconversations.com/2016/08/01/integrating-proxy-with-docker-swarm-tour-around-docker-1-12-series/

Comment: This is great but I still lose availability because if a node is down it won't be able to forward the request. So if I open my firewall to route requests on port 32400 to one of my nodes that will work as long as that node is not down. Is that right?

Comment: @user3063045 Fair point, but the same single point of failure would exist if you ran a load balancing node, such as HA proxy. This is where DNS based load balancing comes in methinks. Do you have a DNS server that you control? You could then place all the swarm nodes under the same entry.